# Парсинг содержимого web-интерфейса роутера (Кто подключен)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautiful-soup, bs4

Есть код:

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

path_to_chromedriver = '/Users/ynr/Desktop/chromedriver'

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)

browser.get('http://192.168.1.2')

password = browser.find_element_by_id('pcPassword')
password.send_keys('**********')
passwordbtn = browser.find_element_by_id('login-btn')
passwordbtn.click()

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 100)

requiredHtml = browser.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(requiredHtml, 'html5lib')
print(soup)
```

Выдает некий результат:

```html
<body id="mainBody">
    <div id="base" style="background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);"></div>
    <div id="top"><div class="singleLanguage" id="top-con" style="width: 988px;">
    <div>
        <a href="http://www.tp-link.com/en/" id="top-product" target="_blank">
            <span id="top-product-name">Archer D2</span>
        </a>
        <div class="top-nav" id="top-nav">
            <ul id="ul-nav">
                <li id="qs">
                    <span class="T_qs">Quick Setup</span>
                </li>
                <li class="selected" id="basic">
                    <span class="T_basic">Basic</span>
                </li>
                <li id="advanced">
                    <span class="T_adv">Advanced</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="top-country nd">
            <select class="top-country-select" id="top-country">
            <option value="en_US">English</option></select>
        </div>
        <div class="top-control">
            <!-- <div class="top-lang"></div> -->
            <a class="top-btn" href="javascript:void(0);" id="topLogout">
                <span class="icon"></span>
                <span class="text T_logout">Log out</span>
            </a>
            <a class="top-btn" href="javascript:void(0);" id="topReboot">
                <span class="icon"></span>
                <span class="text T_reboot">Reboot</span>
            </a>
            <a class="top-btn nd" href="javascript:void(0);" id="topUpdate">
                <span class="icon">
                    <span class="icon" id="topUpdate-number">1</span>
                </span>
                <span class="text T_update">Update</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

А мне нужно извлечь все данные всех элементов, а то что выдает код - это содержание без учета скрытых разделов

Comment: Непонятно что из приведенного HTML вы хотите извлечь

Comment: в том то и дело что конкретно в показанном html этого нет, оно скрыто в подразделах, а они не показываются здесь, я не знаю как отобразить весь html

Comment: Наверное, эти подразделы показываются при взаимодействии, поэтому через селениум взаимодействуйте с страницей (например, кликайте по ним)